# Reading specific portions of a file

Tags: windows, powershell, text

I am currently working on creating an admin tool in Powershell and I am relatively new to the language, so I apologize if this is a dumb question. I am creating a list box using system.windows.forms. I am calling the information that will be in the list box from a .cfg file which will point to the directories where each of the items (in this case batch files) are located. I am also going to be including a description when an Item is selected, so I will need to call this as well. If its possible, how do you independently select two strings of text from the same line in a file?

Comment: I don't think you included enough information. Are they delimited in some way? eg. `"setting1","setting2"` But really it sounds like a better option would rather than use a flat "`.cfg`"  text file, use a `.psd1` and use `Import-PowerShellDataFile` or a JSON and `ConvertFrom-JSON`.

Comment: I just found some items regarding delimiters and escape characters for powershell which will be very useful. Thank you.

Comment: I am looking at JSON as well, which would be a better option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `-match` to check for specific strings within a block of text. As BenH mentioned above though using something like JSON or even XML would be much easier to pull information out of.

If you go the route of using `-match` you can us `$matches` to see what has been matched and use that information.